# Trying to use react-player throws a Hydration error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-player, hydration

Hi how are you? I'm trying to use `react-player` in my Next.js app without any luck.

This code

```
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

const Home = () => {
return (
  <div>
    <p>Here is my video!!</p>
    <div className={s.wrapper}>
      <ReactPlayer src='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zohpogt56Bg' width="100%" 
       height="100%" className={s.player} />
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```

keeps throwing this error: Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Does anybody knows what is going on? thanks!

Comment: Your function doesn't have a return?

Comment: I'm having the same problem (using the url prop). versions are as follows:
```"next": "12.1.6",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-dom": "18.1.0",
"react-player": "^2.10.1"```

Answer (score 42):

You can change your import to utilize Next's dynamic import. If you are only using static site generation then this option should work for you. It does seem like a bandaid fix however, because I don't think it solves the root problem.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const ReactPlayer = dynamic(() => import("react-player"), { ssr: false });
```

Comment: How do I get typescript information?

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried [this](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/issues/1428)?

It's basically checking the window.

```
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";

const Home = () => {
const [hasWindow, setHasWindow] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      setHasWindow(true);
    }
  }, []);
return (
  <div>
    <p>Here is my video!!</p>
    <div className={s.wrapper}>
      {
        hasWindow && <ReactPlayer src='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zohpogt56Bg' 
        width="100%" 
        height="100%" className={s.player} />
    }
    </div>
  </div>
)}
```